# Problems with includes() function and array comparsion

Tags: arrays, include, comparison

As a part of whole procedure, I want to compare user's input (as array) with union of two randomly given arrays. I can not use array.sort() and comparison of arrays element by element, because it's enough to have just one different element in input array and after sorting more than just one element will be identified as "wrong one" (example: array "union" after sorting = [11,13,17,18], array "upis" (user's input) after sorting = [7,11,13,18] so if I compare element by element, which I've tried in original code, all first three elements are identified as wrong...)

That's why I've switched to array.includes() and I've spend last 5.5 hours trying to find where am I wrong and just can't find it so I'm going slightly mad... In few hours I'm supposed to be at work but I'm losing my mind because of this...

**THE PROBLEM IS WITHIN checkInput() FUNCTION...** The code just won't and won't recognize input elements (array "upis") within "union" array... Can't figure out why???

Any help more then appreciated!

```
<script>
  //-----------  1.) Kreiraj dva nasumična niza i uniju  -----------
  var arrA = []; //od 3 do max 6 članova
  var arrB = []; //od 2 do max 5 članova
  while (arrA.length < Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 3) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    if (arrA.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arrA[arrA.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  while (arrB.length < Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    if (arrB.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arrB[arrB.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  var union = [...new Set([...arrA, ...arrB])];
  document.write("A = " + arrA + "<br>");
  document.write("B = " + arrB + "<br>");

  //-----------  2.) Funkcija za dodavanje text box-ova  -----------
  function addFields() {
    // Broj text box-ova koje treba kreirati
    var number = union.length;
    // <div> u koji će se dinamično dodati text box-ovi
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    // Obriši prethodni zapis u <div>
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
      container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    // Tekst A U B
    //container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("A ∪ B = "));
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      // Kreiraj <input> element i definiraj stil
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.id = "element" + i;
      input.style.width = 25;
      container.appendChild(input);
      // Dodaj zarez poslije svakog input box-a, osim posljednjeg
      if (i < number - 1) {
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(", "));
      }
    }
    // Pokaži gumb Provjeri
    document.getElementById("provj").style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  //-----------  3.) Provjera upisa  -----------
  function checkInput() {
    var upis = [];
    var greske = [];
    // Pohrani upis u niz
    for (i = 0; i < union.length; i++) {
      var privr = document.getElementById("element" + i).value;
      upis.push(privr);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < upis.length; i++) {
      // ako je neko polje nepopunjeno, obavijesti i prekini petlju
      if (upis[i] === "") {
        alert("Treba upisati sve članove unije skupova!");
        greske = [];
        //npr. prva dva upisa kriva, ostala polja nepopunjena - iako ima
        //praznih polja, prekida se procedura ali se kod prva dva upisa
        //popunio niz greške i onda će ih pokazati
        break;
      }
      // u protivnom
      else {
        var n = union.includes(upis[i]);
        alert(upis[i] + " " + n);
        if (n === false) {
          greske.push(upis[i]);
        } else {
          //ništa
        }
      }
    }
    if (greske.length > 0) {
      alert("Krivo upisani članovi: " + greske);
    }
  }

</script>

<div id="container">
  <button onclick="addFields()">Upiši članove unije</button>
</div>
<button id="provj" style="visibility:hidden" onclick="checkInput()">Provjeri</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing numbers with `strings`. Just add `+` to the `includes` parameter:

```
var n = union.includes(+upis[i]);
```

This will force the string to be `unboxed` as a number and your `includes` will work as expected.

You other option is to convert those strings to numbers and then no `unboxing` will be needed.

Comment: Akrion, you saved my day!!!! Stupid stupid stupid me :-( I've lost almost all night looking for an error and it didn't even occur to me that these are text inputs, not numbers!!!! I can't thank you enough!